# When is a variable a AnyObject but not a NSObject

Tags: swift, types, nsobject, any, anyobject

Imagine a variable declared as below:

let sample : AnyObject = "anyobject" as AnyObject

Now when I try to retrieve the type of the var sample, it shows as NSObject.

Following is the code snippet:

```
   let sample : AnyObject = "anyobject" as AnyObject

        if sample is NSObject {
            print("Type is NSObject")
        }

        if sample is AnyObject {
            print("Type is AnyObject")
        }

        if sample is Any {
            print("Type is Any")
        }
```

And the output is:

```
Type is NSObject
Type is AnyObject
Type is Any
```

I thought the output would be AnyObject and Any since AnyObject is a subset of Any. But it did show NSObject as well.

My Question is: 
1. When is a variable a AnyObject but **not** a NSObject?
2. When is a variable type Any but **not** NSObject?

As per my understanding,

NSObject is a subset of AnyObject. NSObject is the base class for most ObjC objects.
AnyObject is a subset of Any. AnyObject is an instance of any class type.
Any is a representation of an instance of any type at all, including function types and optional types.

Please correct me if I am wrong with the above understanding.
Sorry I am kind of new to Objc and need help in understanding the concepts. Any website url which explains these concepts would be useful. Thanks in Advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On platforms with Objective-C compatibility (which means all of Apple's platforms and no others), every class type is (secretly) a subclass of [the `SwiftObject` class](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/SwiftObject.h), which provides `NSObject` protocol conformance.

On other platforms, `NSObject` is “just another class”, [implemented in Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSObject.swift), so only a class that explicitly has `NSObject` as a superclass has instances that are `NSObject`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob! That was so helpful. I was struck on this since a day now!